# Strange error in python3 when doing big int calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to do this in Python 3.5.2:

```
int(204221389795918291262976/10000)
```

but got the unexpected result: `20422138979591827456`

It's working fine in Python 2.7.12, result is: `20422138979591829126L`

Any idea why Python 3 gave me the wrong result?

Comment: Your first error was assuming similar results, really. Python 2 and Python 3 share many similar traits but also differ in various aspects. Don't take behavior in one implementation granted for another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python 3 you have to use integer division `//` explicitly or else float division will apply even between 2 integers.

That's one of the major changes between python 2 and python 3

In your example: (will work both in python 2 and python 3 so it's backwards compatible!)

```
204221389795918291262976//10000
20422138979591829126
```

(you don't even need to convert to `int` here, result is `int` since both terms are `int`)

BTW if you want to make this bug work with python 2 it is also possible :)

```
from __future__ import division
```