# Handling big numbers in Python 3 for calculating combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a Python 3 script that calculates combinations in the following way

```
def permutate(n, k):

    if k == 0:
        return 1
    elif n < n - k + 1:
        return n
    else:
        return n * permutate(n - 1, k - 1)


def choose(n, k):

    if k > n / 2:
    k = n - k

    return int(permutate(n, k) / permutate(k, k))
```

So my problem is when handling big numbers,

```
choose(5, 3)
```

yields 10 which is correct.

```
choose(1000, 1)
choose(52, 4)
choose(1000, 5)
choose(1000, 999)
```

These all yield the correct result, however when I try to pass

```
choose(1000, 800)
```

I get the wrong result, the head of part of my resulting integer is correct but when I reach the tail part of the integer it is not correct, which leads me to believe that the problem lies in Python trying to handle the division of the two very large numbers in the choose function.

```
return int(permutate(n, k) / permutate(k, k))
```

I'm sorry if I broke any rules or if the code formatting is way off, officially my first post :)

Comment: Do you know about `//` (integer division)? By the way -- good first post. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python per se. Floating point arithmetics are known to cause trouble due to precision errors. Either use integer division or switch to fractions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange error in python3 when doing big int calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308302/strange-error-in-python3-when-doing-big-int-calculation)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are correct that the background issue is the same in both cases, but the context in which it arises seems to be sufficiently different so that it isn't an outright duplicate.

Comment: @JohnColeman: my honesty paid off I even got an upvote on the linked question. thanks for your comments :) I agree it's easy to declare 2 questions duplicate when you find out that the root cause is the same, not before... I bet there are a ton of topics like that on meta :)

Comment: @JohnColeman given the 2 other answers that propose a different approach, may not be a duplicate after all :) BTW: nice first question you're right. Deserves another upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is: all your divisions use floating point whereas they are clearly targeted as integer.

Python 3 acts differently from Python 2.

```
3/2 => 1.5
3//2 => 1
```

Replace `/` by `//` (no need to cast in integer like you did)

```
return permutate(n, k) // permutate(k, k)
```

also here (less important)

```
if k > n // 2
```

Comment: Well if n and k are ints to start off with that would work. But if one of them becomes a float (he pass a float in) `//` would still yield a float division. Maybe cast the inputs to ints before passing them in if he needs to ensure they are ints?

Comment: where do you see he pass a float in? it's just large integers. I suspect he used `int` because he noticed that it returned `floats`

Comment: I'm just saying he only shows that he is passing large ints, but what if he passes a float in. Just trying to give him more details, but maybe that's not needed.

Comment: this may be a duplicate: I even answered at the time.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308302/strange-error-in-python3-when-doing-big-int-calculation

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, which uses the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html) module to (by reducing to lowest terms) do the division as it goes along. It also uses the fact that e.g. `choose(100,70) = choose(100,30)` so as to not do unneeded multiplication:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def choose(n,k):
    if k > n//2: k = n - k
    p = Fraction(1)
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        p *= Fraction(n - i + 1, i)
    return int(p)
```

for example,

```
>>> choose(10000,100)
65208469245472575695415972927215718683781335425416743372210247172869206520770178988927510291340552990847853030615947098118282371982392705479271195296127415562705948429404753632271959046657595132854990606768967505457396473467998111950929802400
```

(which can be verified with a computer algebra system).

It is reasonably fast, taking about a second to find all 54341 digits of `choose(10**9, 10000)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for correctness/brevity**

---

I have another approach that would take the load away from division and put it on multiplication. I would suggest taking advantage of the definition of combinations. Since combinations and permutations are counting techniques, losing precision through arithmetic operations is not good craftsmanship.

In the combination, you wanna cancel out the common factors in the numerator and the denominator as best as you can so that you can. So I'd say ditch your permutation function altogether, and your combination function would be something like...

```
    def permute(n, k):
        // P(n,k) = n!/(n-k)!  mathematically
        largest_dividable_number = max(k, n-k)
        output_value = 1
        starting_value = n
        for i in range(1,largest_dividable_number - 1):
            output_value = output_value * starting_value
            starting_value = starting_value - 1
        return output_value

    def choose(n, k):
        p = permute(n,k)
        return p//math.factorial(k)
```

Comment: I let the OP tell us if it's useful for him (it looks like it), but you'll be better off (again) by changing `int(p/int(k))` to `p//k` (integer division in python 3, again :))

Comment: Made the change. I do think that he will be dealing with smaller numbers, generally speaking, if he takes advantage of the arithmetic definition of combination.

Comment: you don't even have to cast to int if inputs are integers.